# ASP .NET membership custom error message on creating new user?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

```
<add name="MyMembershipProvider" 
     type="BlueDDApp.Controllers.MyMembershipProvider" 
     connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
     enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
     enablePasswordReset="true" 
     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
     requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
     minRequiredPasswordLength="8"  
     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
     passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!%,.;:])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!%,.;:])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!%,.;:])$"  
     passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
     applicationName="/" />
```

Is there any attribute like `errorMessageMInPasswordLength="custom erroe message"` so that i can easily set custom message when entered password `length<8`

Used the Web Site Administration Tool, which provides a wizard-like interface for creating new users. (To start this tool, click ASP.NET Configuration on the Website menu in the Microsoft Visual Studio)

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce length with a regular expression in `passwordStrengthRegularExpression`.

For example, alphabetic chars only between 8 and 16 chars in length : `"^[a-zA-Z]{8,16}$"`

Comment: Ok Ira i can but what's the use of it.?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? You asked how to enforce the minimum length of password. That's how to do it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misread it. You could still use the regex to stop people from setting their password to something too short. This really comes down to validation anyway rather than the membership rules.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `InvalidPasswordErrorMessage` in the `CreateUserWizard` control.